# curious native crash under ART which starting LooperThreads

Tags: android, art-runtime

I am starting a bank of LooperThreads in my app on startup but it seems to be crashing under art

Googling the first line turned up this reference in the art source code - looks like there might be some problem suspending the Looper threads after they have started. or from the below link possibly starting a thread which GCing?

SEE LINE 77
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/05c87be/src/thread_list.cc

I dont really have a clue what is going on but I guess I have better fix it before all phone have ART runtime enabled by default which is happening soonish i think.

below is a partial dump: the full trace is posted here:
http://pastebin.com/MiFa6fLD

The code for first part of the ImageController (with threads stuff) is here :
http://pastebin.com/xiJ9N9fK

```
    E/art     (21260): Thread[20,tid=21302,Native,Thread*=0x49220970,peer=0x00000000,"ImageThread:2"] suspend count already zero.
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/thread.cc:538] DALVIK THREADS (20):

        F/art     (21260): art/runtime/thread.cc:538]   | stack=0x49702000-0x49706000 stackS

ize=1040KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/thread.cc:538]   (no managed stack frames)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/thread.cc:538] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/thread.cc:538] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Runtime aborting...
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Aborting thread:
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x6462fac8 self=0x4172aaf0
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21260 nice=19 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x40097154
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=R schedstat=( 146504488 117958692 657 ) utm=11 stm=3 core=3 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0xbe445000-0xbe449000 stackSize=8MB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::Thread::DumpStack(std::ostream&) const+87 [0x41676edc] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x4166f06c] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::Runtime::Abort()+79 [0x4166f5fc] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+505 [0x4151c93a] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x4167a9d6] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::ThreadList::Resume(art::Thread*, bool)+151 [0x416810e0] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x41655d38] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Thread.nativeSetName(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Thread.setName(Thread.java:911)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - locked <0x65711840> (a co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.img.ImageController$LooperThread)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.img.ImageController.startThreads(ImageController.java:209)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.img.ImageController.<init>(ImageController.java:126)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.app.MyPODApplication.onCreate(MyPODApplication.java:111)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: mutator lock
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] All threads:
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] DALVIK THREADS (20):
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Native
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x6462fac8 self=0x4172aaf0
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21260 nice=19 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x40097154
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=R schedstat=( 154916779 118173224 663 ) utm=12 stm=3 core=3 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0xbe445000-0xbe449000 stackSize=8MB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::Thread::DumpStack(std::ostream&) const+87 [0x41676edc] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::ThreadList::DumpLocked(std::ostream&)+67 [0x41681e4c] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x4166f11e] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::Runtime::Abort()+79 [0x4166f5fc] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+505 [0x4151c93a] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x4167a9d6] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::ThreadList::Resume(art::Thread*, bool)+151 [0x416810e0] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x41655d38] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Thread.nativeSetName(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Thread.setName(Thread.java:911)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - locked <0x65711840> (a co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.img.ImageController$LooperThread)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.img.ImageController.startThreads(ImageController.java:209)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.img.ImageController.<init>(ImageController.java:126)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.app.MyPODApplication.onCreate(MyPODApplication.java:111)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "Thread pool worker 0" prio=1 tid=2 Native (still starting up)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x00000000 self=0x4730fe78
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21266 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x441a3970
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 247917 3645 10 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x43f23000-0x43f27000 stackSize=1024KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x441a5dd4] ([anon:libc_malloc])
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   (no managed stack frames)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "Thread pool worker 2" prio=1 tid=3 Native (still starting up)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x00000000 self=0x45feb018
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21268 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x4172b130
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 112656 67917 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x47785000-0x47789000 stackSize=1024KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x441a5dd4] ([anon:libc_malloc])
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   (no managed stack frames)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "Thread pool worker 1" prio=1 tid=4 Native (still starting up)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x00000000 self=0x45feb298
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21267 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x4172aee8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 133696 75053 5 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x44025000-0x44029000 stackSize=1024KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x441a5dd4] ([anon:libc_malloc])
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   (no managed stack frames)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x6552a910 self=0x4730efe8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21269 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x44182510
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 402813 0 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x47885000-0x47889000 stackSize=1016KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x4167306b] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::SignalCatcher::WaitForSignal(art::Thread*, art::SignalSet&)+46 [0x416733d7] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+176 [0x4167494d] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: __thread_entry+72 [0x400b9170] (libc.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: pthread_create+240 [0x400b9308] (libc.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   (no managed stack frames)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "JDWP" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WaitingInMainDebuggerLoop
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x655251e8 self=0x473135f0
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21270 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x473133a8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 1154898 1789998 14 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x47983000-0x47987000 stackSize=1016KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: art::JDWP::JdwpState::Run()+378 [0x415c55f7] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0x415c6873] (libart.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: __thread_entry+72 [0x400b9170] (libc.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: pthread_create+240 [0x400b9308] (libc.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   (no managed stack frames)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "HeapTrimmerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=10 Waiting
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x655287f8 self=0x473161d8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21274 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x473164d8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 63333 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x47d8d000-0x47d91000 stackSize=1040KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: (no native stack frames for thread 21274)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - waiting on <0x60a7ad58> (a java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:299)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - locked <0x60a7ad58> (a java.lang.Daemons$HeapTrimmerDaemon)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "GCDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=11 Waiting
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x65529a00 self=0x47316da0
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21275 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x473170d8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 61771 0 2 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x47e91000-0x47e95000 stackSize=1040KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: (no native stack frames for thread 21275)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Object.wait(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - waiting on <0x60a7ad18> (a java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon.run(Daemons.java:330)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - locked <0x60a7ad18> (a java.lang.Daemons$GCDaemon)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 

    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "pool-1-thread-1" prio=5 tid=15 Native
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x655d6468 self=0x4731ba58
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21294 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x4731bcd8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 79149636 24758908 245 ) utm=7 stm=0 core=1 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x490d6000-0x490da000 stackSize=1040KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: oatexec+3679176 [0x626ed3c8] (system@framework@boot.oat)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at libcore.io.Posix.poll(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.poll(BlockGuardOs.java:119)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at libcore.io.IoBridge.isConnected(IoBridge.java:200)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:161)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:843)

    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "GAThread" prio=5 tid=16 Sleeping
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x655e5fa0 self=0x441709a8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21296 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x44170c28
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 163750 74011 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x492f2000-0x492f6000 stackSize=1040KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: (no native stack frames for thread 21296)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - sleeping on <0x655e6078> (a java.lang.Object)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:1010)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   - locked <0x655e6078> (a java.lang.Object)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:978)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at com.google.analytics.tracking.android.GAThread.run(GAThread.java:482)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 

    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "DB BG Thread" prio=10 tid=14 Native
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x6569efe8 self=0x4731b550
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21299 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x4731b7d0
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 176979 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x48fcd000-0x48fd1000 stackSize=1040KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92 [0x40134869] (libutils.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22 [0x401dd121] (libandroid_runtime.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: oatexec+18030388 [0x6349cf34] (system@framework@boot.oat)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.util.LooperThread.run(LooperThread.java:29)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "ImageThread:0" prio=1 tid=18 Native
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x65710c88 self=0x4921c518
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21300 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x4921c8e8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 295156 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x494fa000-0x494fe000 stackSize=1040KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92 [0x40134869] (libutils.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22 [0x401dd121] (libandroid_runtime.so)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: oatexec+18030388 [0x6349cf34] (system@framework@boot.oat)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   at co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2.img.ImageController$LooperThread.run(ImageController.java:181)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "ImageThread:1" prio=1 tid=19 Native
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x00000000 self=0x4921fd20
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21301 nice=19 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x492200a8
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 58334 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x495fe000-0x49602000 stackSize=1040KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0xfffffc10] (???)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   (no managed stack frames)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] "ImageThread:2" prio=1 tid=20 Native
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x00000000 self=0x49220970
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | sysTid=21302 nice=19 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x49220c90
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | state=S schedstat=( 80261 97864 3 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   | stack=0x49702000-0x49706000 stackSize=1040KB
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   native: ??? [0xfffffc10] (???)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203]   (no managed stack frames)
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/art     (21260): art/runtime/runtime.cc:203] 
    F/libc    (21260): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x0000530c (code=-6), thread 21260 (ImageThread:2)
    I/DEBUG   (  177): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    I/DEBUG   (  177): Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:4.4.2/KOT49H/937116:user/release-keys'
    I/DEBUG   (  177): Revision: '11'
    I/DEBUG   (  177): pid: 21260, tid: 21260, name: ImageThread:2  >>> co.uk.sentinelweb.mypod.v2 <<<
    I/DEBUG   (  177): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     r0 00000000  r1 0000530c  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     r4 00000006  r5 00000000  r6 0000530c  r7 0000010c
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     r8 00000000  r9 bec43d70  sl bec43d68  fp 0000205f
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     ip 416edcac  sp bec43cd8  lr 400befe5  pc 400cdf90  cpsr 00070010
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d0  2f656d69746e7572  d1  2e656d69746e7572
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d2  2030303036303774  d3  7a69536b6361742f
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d4  617265746e695f6e  d5  6373206576697463
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d6  20302f303d646568  d7  303d656c646e6168
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d8  404ccccccccccccc  d9  0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d10 3fd3333333333333  d11 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d16 6567616e616d206f  d17 206b636174732064
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d18 0000000000000000  d19 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d20 0000000000000032  d21 0000004400000044
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d24 0000000000000000  d25 0002a7600002a760
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d26 0707070703030303  d27 0300000004000000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d28 0800000009000000  d29 0001000000010000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     d30 010b400001088000  d31 01108000010e0000
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     scr 60000010
    I/DEBUG   (  177): 
    I/DEBUG   (  177): backtrace:
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #00  pc 00021f90  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #01  pc 00012fe1  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+48)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #02  pc 000131f5  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #03  pc 00011f2b  /system/lib/libc.so
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #04  pc 00021844  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #05  pc 00195655  /system/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort()+168)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #06  pc 0004293b  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+506)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #07  pc 001a09d7  /system/lib/libart.so
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #08  pc 001a70e1  /system/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Resume(art::Thread*, bool)+152)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #09  pc 0017bd39  /system/lib/libart.so
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #10  pc 0009b310  /data/dalvik-cache/system@framework@boot.oat
    I/DEBUG   (  177): 
    I/DEBUG   (  177): stack:
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43c98  4924f880  [anon:libc_malloc]
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43c9c  fffffbcc  
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43ca0  bec43d3c  [stack]
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43ca4  4924f888  [anon:libc_malloc]
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43ca8  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cac  400bd257  /system/lib/libc.so (dlfree+50)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cb0  400f6000  /system/lib/libc.so
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cb4  4924f888  [anon:libc_malloc]
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cb8  4924f888  [anon:libc_malloc]
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cbc  fffffbcc  
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cc0  bec43d3c  [stack]
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cc4  400b9c0d  /system/lib/libc.so (free+12)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cc8  402b8390  /system/lib/libstlport.so
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43ccc  4151c877  /system/lib/libart.so (art::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+310)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cd0  400fa384  
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cd4  414d7f00  [anon:libc_malloc]
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #00  bec43cd8  00000006  
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cdc  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43ce0  0000530c  
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43ce4  416edcac  /system/lib/libart.so
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43ce8  416edcac  /system/lib/libart.so
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cec  400befe5  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #01  bec43cf0  00000006  
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cf4  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cf8  bec43db8  [stack]
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43cfc  400bf1f9  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+14)
    I/DEBUG   (  177):     #02  bec43d00  bec43d0c  [stack]
    I/DEBUG   (  177):          bec43d04  400bdf2f  /system/lib/libc.so
I/DEBUG   (  177):
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your `MyPODApplication` and `ImageController` classes?

Comment: pasted the top part with the Looper threading code here:http://pastebin.com/xiJ9N9fK

Comment: Try calling setName() and setPriority() before calling start().

Comment: That seems to have got it. what was the clue if you don't mind me asking. If you answer the question i can award bounty. :) Thanks!